# numpy argmax with groupby

Tags: python, numpy, argmax

Suppose I have labels to cluster data into several groups. Now I want to find the indices of the maximum w.r.t the original array for each cluster. For example:

```
import numpy as np
labels = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
y = np.random.randint(0, 9, len(labels)) #array([6, 7, 5, 4, 2, 8, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4])
```

I want [1, 5] because for cluster 1, the max is 7 at index 1 and for cluster 0, the max is 8 at index 5. Is it possible to get that without for loop?

My naive solution for reference:

```
out = []
for i in [0, 1]:
    temp = y.copy()
    temp[labels == i] = -1
    out.append(np.argmax(temp))
```

Comment: shouldn't the 8 be at index 2 in this case?

Comment: 2 if we only consider the grouped array, but 5 with respect to the original array

Comment: I believe this answer would work, however it still looks a bit ugly to me. I will try to improve it when I get time tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
labels = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
y = np.array([6, 7, 5, 4, 2, 8, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4])
arr = np.unique(labels)

result = np.ma.masked_where(labels[:,None] == arr, np.tile(y,(arr.shape[0],1)).T).argmax(axis=0)
```

The main idea is that we force the 1D array to broadcast by adding a new dimension. Then we have to also create the same dimensions for the second array, but this lets us compare as many values as we want without looping.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution.